# My tweepy Twitter bot is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

It returns several errors and most of them show: `<framework not available>`

I'm new at coding and I'm just trying making a bot for fun with the Twitter API but had a lot of errors and I don't know what to do.

The main error that appears is this one:

> (from collections import namedtuple, Mapping ImportError: cannot
> import name 'Mapping' from 'collections')

can someone help me please?

```py
import tweepy

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("", "")
auth.set_access_token("", "")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Pegar ID do bot
bot_id = int(api.me().id_str)


class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, tweet):
        print("tweet encontrado!")
        print(f"TWEET: {tweet.author.scream_name} - {tweet.text}")
        if tweet.author.id != bot_id and tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is None:
            if not tweet.retweeted:
                try:
                    print("Tentando retuite...")
                    api.retweet(tweet.id)
                    print("Retuitado com sucesso!")
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)


stream_listener = MyStreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, Listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(track=['Squirrel', 'Squirrels', 'squirrel', 'squirrels', 'Esquilo', 'Esquilos'], languages=['en', 'pt'])
```

The erros that appeers:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\wgama\PycharmProjects\botesquilo\botesquilo.py", line 1, in 
import tweepy
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tweepy_*init*_.py", line 12, in 
from tweepy.api import API
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 15, in 
import requests
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests_*init*_.py", line 43, in 
import urllib3
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3_*init*_.py", line 8, in 
from .connectionpool import (
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in 
from .connection import (
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in 
from .util.ssl_ import (
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from .connection import is_connection_dropped
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in 
from .wait import wait_for_read
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in 
from .selectors import (
File "C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in 
from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\wgama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections_*init*_.py)

Comment: What's the _full_ error message?

Comment: You should make sure that the version of tweepy you're using is compatible with your Python version

Comment: There is indeed no `Mapping` class in [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html). I don't think there ever has been one. Whatever library you're relying on uses yet another library, or has a bug.

Comment: My bad: for Python 3.0 to 3.3, there was `collections.Mapping`. It has now moved to `collections.abc.Mapping`. It would seem you're using a *very* old version of `tweepy` or some other dependency.

Comment: `collections.Mapping` was deprecated in Python 3.3, but wasn't removed until Python 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

As investigated in the comments, the problem comes from the fact that you are using an old version of Tweepy which is incompatible with Python 3.10.

So an update to the lastest version of Tweepy (currently 4.8.0) should solve your problem.

But please note that the `API.me()` method have been removed since the 4.0.0 version of Tweepy, so you will have to replaced it by the [API.verify_credentials()](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.verify_credentials) method.

*Edit :* I just read your code more carefully and I could have found other mistakes: there is not `author` field in a tweet object but a `user` field, and I guess you meant `screen_name` instead of `scream_name` (!). Finally, after your update to the lastest version of Tweepy, you will also have to replace `tweepy.StreamListener` by `tweepy.Stream`.